# Okta API - Login user without a password (create session token)

Tags: okta, okta-api

I'm working on a custom passwordless authentication solution that should integrate with Okta. I've found that creating users without a password is relatively easy but I also need to find a way to login a user through the Okta API without having to use a password (as there isn't one).

I've been looking into the API docs and found that my end goal is to create a session token which can be exchanged for a session cookie. To get such a token I need to use the authentication API because every authentication process has to start with a call to the primary authentication endpoint which is /api/v1/authn

The problem is that the call this endpoint requires a password to be sent which is irrelevant in the passwordless use-case. Okta does support various in-house passwordless solutions such as their WebAuthn implementation so there must be a way to generate a session without the user's password.

So how can I login a user that has no password through Okta API?

Comment: Check Okta's IDX API https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js which is used with their new OIE engine, which supports passwordless autN.

Comment: Could you point me to the relevant API docs? I couldn't find any option to login a user without a password.
As I mentioned in the post - I was able to register a user without a password through an API call but now have to understand how to create a session as my custom solution is the one who should login the user instead of Okta itself.
I just want to use the Okta API to store user info and create sessions.